# The emoticon icon no longer produces emoticon choices. How can I get them back?

Tags: gmail

When I used to click the Gmail emoticon button, a goodly number of them would appear. Suddenly, all of them have vanished. I saw nothing in Gmail settings relating to emoticons. They really did help me express myself better in Gmail. How can I get them back?

Macbook Air mid-2012, Mac OS X 10.8.5

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Probably gmail as been updated, you can try do refresh your cache with this command shortcut `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R`
But it may vary depending on you browser / system check this url to know exactly the steps for your configuration : http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/

[image: gmail empticons]